# Query to find all DVDs not out on rent

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
    Item: Item Name, Format (D/B), Item_ID
    Rentals: Item_ID, date_borrowed, date_returned
```

I need to find all DVDs (format D) which are not out on rental on this point in time. Can anyone share a join query I could use? I'm using the code below but the result is only giving back 16 of 56 expected elements

```
SELECT*from Item LEFT JOIN transactions on Item.Item_ID = transactions.Item_ID WHERE date_returned is not NULL and format = 'D';
```

Comment: SELECT * from Item WHERE format = 'D' and Item.Item_ID NOT IN (SELECT Item_ID FROM transactions WHERE transactions.date_returned IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

The join itself is pretty simple:

```
SELECT * FROM Item i 
LEFT JOIN Rentals r on R.Item_ID = i.Item_ID
WHERE r.date_borrowed IS NULL AND i.Format = "D";
```

but you may need more logic in your database, as "Not rented at this moment" can be quantified a few different ways.

Comment: Makes a big assumption that Rentals only contains active rentals.  Based on the information provided the question is basically unanswerable.  For example if a dvd has never been rented will it show up in rentals?  is it out if date_borrowed is not null and date_returned is., etc...

Comment: Only DVDs which have been rented are in the transactions table. It is unavailable if date_borrowed is not null and date_returned is null. I need to select all DVDs in the Item table, discounting DVDs which are out on rent. Thanks

Comment: @TimLewis. Sorry I should have specified that the DVDs will not be listed in the transaction table unless they have been rented so 'date_borrowed is null' will not work here. I tried it with 'date_returned is not null' but it isn't returning what I expected

Comment: @Richie Er, yes it will ??!?!?